# Ember Data Request GET /vt/sys/auth returned a 403 Payload

Tags: hashicorp-vault, vault, hashicorp

I am new to vault. I am currently setting up a key vault in dev mode on my Linux system using Docker Compose.

I have successfully run the docker container using docker-compose and initialized the vault using the `vault init operator` command. However, I encountered an error message below when attempting to authenticate into the UI.

```bash
Ember Data Request GET /vt/sys/auth returned a 403 Payload (apolication/son) Tabied Obiect permission denied
```

Here is my docker-compose file

```bash
version: '2'
services:
  vault:
    image: vault:1.13.3
    container_name: vault
    ports:
      - "8200:8200"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/logs:/logs
      - ./volumes/file:/file
      - ./volumes/config:/config
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    entrypoint: vault server -config=/config/vault.json
```

Here is my vault configuration file

```bash
{
  "backend": {
    "file": {
      "path": "/vault/file"
    }
  },
  "listener": {
    "tcp":{
      "address": "0.0.0.0:8200",
      "tls_disable": 1
    }
  },
  "ui": true
}
```

I will be grateful for your help

Comment: What credentials are you using to try to sign in?

Comment: Thank you for your response @lxop and sorry for the delay. After running the container, it generated 5 keys which I used 3 to unseal the cluster. After that, I ran the command ```vault login s.xyz``` (s.xyz represents the token)

Comment: Where did you get the token from? It might help if you show all of your interactions with Vault - I assume nothing is sensitive at this point since you're just experimenting?

Comment: What is that `/vt` ? Shouldn't it be `/v1` ?

Comment: @ixe013 it looks to me like they have taken a photo of the error message then used OCR to copy it out of the photo into this question. There are a few typo-looking things in that quote

Comment: @ixe013 and lxop. Apologies for the late replies. My server has been down for days now.  The error message is exactly as I copied it. I will send a screenshot once my server is up. Thank you for your assistance.